# How to separate two regions in DensityPlot

Tags: plotting

I want to separate two regions in DensityPlot similar to the attached image.

[image: density plot]

In my code and the obtained result, I want to separate the region with less value of one from others. How can I do this? My code is as follows:

```
A[m_, κ_, Δ_, Ω_, λ_,c_, Ν_, M_] := (
  2 m {(κ + (Δ^2 - Ω^2 - λ^2)/κ)^2 + 4 Ω^2} + 
   c {λ^2 (1 + Ν) -  2 λ  M (Δ + Ω) + (κ^2 + (Δ + Ω)^2) Ν})/(
  2 {(κ + (Δ^2 - Ω^2 -  λ^2)/κ)^2 + 4 Ω^2} + 
   c {κ^2 + (Δ + Ω)^2 -   λ^2});
DensityPlot[
 A[1000, 0.1, 5, 0.1, λ, 1000, \[ScriptCapitalN], 
  Sqrt[\[ScriptCapitalN] (\[ScriptCapitalN] + 1)]], {λ, 4.991,
   5.008}, {\[ScriptCapitalN], 2, 20}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"λ", "\[ScriptCapitalN]" }, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
 PlotRange -> All, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 20]]
```

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "separate the region with less value of one from other". Do you mean the region where the value of the function is `< 1`? Take a look at `ContourPlot`.

Comment: Yes, but I do not want to use `ContourPlot`. I want to use `DensityPlot` and then separate two different regions.

Comment: Separate how? Show in a different color?

Comment: By line. similar to the graph that I added.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the options [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html), [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) and [`MeshStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html):

```
DensityPlot[A[1000, 0.1, 5, 0.1, λ, 1000, \[ScriptCapitalN], 
  Sqrt[\[ScriptCapitalN] (\[ScriptCapitalN] + 1)]], {λ, 4.98, 
  5.02}, {\[ScriptCapitalN], 2, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"λ", "\[ScriptCapitalN]"}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
 PlotRange -> All, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
 Mesh -> {{1}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, White]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As commented you can use `ContourPlot`. I used OP's boundary setup.

```
p1 = DensityPlot[
   A[1000, 0.1, 5, 0.1, λ, 1000, \[ScriptCapitalN], 
    Sqrt[\[ScriptCapitalN] (\[ScriptCapitalN] + 1)]], {λ, 
    4.991, 5.008}, {\[ScriptCapitalN], 2, 20}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"λ", "\[ScriptCapitalN]"}, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
   PlotRange -> All, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 20]];

p2 = ContourPlot[
   A[1000, 0.1, 5, 0.1, λ, 1000, \[ScriptCapitalN], 
     Sqrt[\[ScriptCapitalN] (\[ScriptCapitalN] + 1)]] ==  1,
{λ, 4.991, 5.008}, {\[ScriptCapitalN], 2, 20},  ContourStyle -> White];
    Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]